# Access remote data through aspx application

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ruby

My workplace keeps client records in a database which is accessible via an aspx application hosted on our local network.  The page allows logging in, simple searching, and retrieving of information, which is displayed on this webpage.  A task I am performing requires I access each record, copy a block of text into a new database which we are creating, and move to the next record (thousands of times).

My question is, is there a way to automate this?  I've looked at browser macros, but the task of searching for each record does not allow for a simple macro interface.  I was hoping to write a program which directly interacts with the aspx application without the need for the browser.  In the code I'd be able to tell the application which records i'm looking for (by date, or unique ID, for example), and have the aspx application return the appropriate fields of text I need.  I don't have any back-end access to the aspx application (it is a third party, proprietary application and their developers are not interested in helping me with this task)

1. Can this be done?
2. If yes, in broad terms, what sort of solution should I be looking at?  Is there a particular language that is more suitable to this task?

Any help is appreciated.  I realize the question is a bit vague and broad, but the third-party application is only hosted locally so I can't give an example.  I know a little ruby, and came across the gem Mechanize, which looks like it might work... but I can't find much about interacting with asp.net

Comment: Why not just access the database directly? The act of scripting an application to retrieve data from a database that you own seems excessively Rube Goldberg.

Comment: Agreed. Very Rube Goldberg.  Unfortunately, the database and application are proprietary (third party), as I said above, and I don't have access to the backend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're on the right track with ruby mechanize. Mechanize will keep track of the cookies for you and  make it easy to submit forms (logging in, asp doPostBack actions). Give it a try, and if you get stuck, post specifics in a new question.

Comment: Thanks.  I've done some more reading on Mechanize and I agree, that is the way to go.  Looks like it's going to be a lot of work.  For anyone else with this question, I found a great tutorial on Mechanize, scraping, and coding in general: http://ruby.bastardsbook.com/chapters/web-scraping/

Comment: I'm actually not crazy about that tutorial. For scraping asp pages specifically with ruby mechanize, consider [starting here](http://scraperblog.blogspot.com/2012/10/asp-forms-with-dopostback-using-ruby.html) * self-plug.